# IE getelementbyid for object in the document

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I need to getElementById for an object which already exists in the document.
In the example, I would like to get the element "test" which is sub of `parentDiv1`.
It works fine in FF but not with IE. Any tips?

Example:

```
<div id="parentDiv1">
    <ul id="test1">test</ul>
</div>
<div id="parentDiv2">
    <ul id="test2">test</ul>
</div>
<script>
    var prtDiv1 = document.getElementById("parentDiv1");
    var test1 = prtDiv1.getElementById("test1");
</script>
```

Comment: You should not have elements with duplicate IDs.

Comment: OP's script referred to `#test1`, so it isn't a duplicate ID problem, rather a typo. I've fixed that.

Comment: what's wrong with just doing `document.getElementById("test1");`? IDs need to be unique in the DOM in order to conform to the HTML spec.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have more than one element with the same id in your document. Use a class. The *easiest* way for you to do what you want then would be to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and write `$('#parentDiv1 ul.test')` to select your element. Other than jQuery, you would need to implement `getElementsByClassName` in javascript in IE because afaik it still doesn't support it natively.

Edit: Make sure there aren't any "name" attributes that have the same value as the target id, and also that the js variable you're setting has a different name than the target id.

Comment: OP's script referred to `#test1`, so it isn't a duplicate ID problem, rather a typo. I've fixed that.

Comment: Try setting the name of the variable to something other than the dom id.  I seem to remember IE having some sort of problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getElementById` on a node is non-standard... If you want to get the element with ID `test1` (as it is its id, this one should be unique) and check that it is a child of element with ID `parentDiv1` rather use this :

```
// get the node with ID `test1` in the document
var test1 = document.getElementById("test1"); 

// Check if it is a child of `parentDiv1`
var isChild = document.getElementById("parentDiv1").contains(test1);
```

You can look at MDN doc about `contains` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains).